# how do I prevent jquery ajax to encode certain chars on data parameter?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am using jquery ajax to query data from a three party web service
the problem is that I need to pass the colon char `:` as part of the data, without encoding it but $.ajax method is automaticaly encoding all non alphabetic chars. so the question is
how do I prevent jquery ajax to encode certain chars on data parameter?
**update**
I know that the colon is encoded because I see it with Firebug
**update**
if i use this on the browser url box I get my desired data
http://example.com?callback=jsonp1316104718105&quit=20100299222.0&show=name:fransisco
if i use this on the browser url box I get wrong data
http://example.com?callback=jsonp1316104718105&quit=20100299222.0&show=name%3Afransisco
the problem is that $.ajax is compiling the last one

Comment: Please make an example of what your parameter looks like before and after jQuery's encoding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a string:

```
$.ajax({
   data: "colons=::::::::",
   processData: false,
   ....
});
```