# Can't get ISO-8601 JSON DateTime to properly send in GET

Tags: c#, json, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have a KnockoutJS viewmodel I'm working with, and sending a JSON date as a parameter in a GET request to WebAPI apparently is difficult.

I've got the following happening to my request

```
var params = {
    userId: currentUser, 
    startRange: ko.toJSON(self.selectedDate()),
    endRange: ko.toJSON(self.selectedDate())
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: params, 
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        sf.setModuleHeaders(xhr);
    }
}).done(function(data) {

}).fail(function () {

}).always(function() {

});
```

On my WebAPI controller, the Start and End dates keep coming up null

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetViolationsInRange(int userId, DateTime? startRange, DateTime? endRange)
```

Inspecting the request, this is what it outputs

```
/API/Cert/GetViolationsInRange?userId=20&startRange=%222015-09-01T04%3A00%3A00.000Z%22&endRange=%222015-09-01T04%3A00%3A00.000Z%22
```

Any ideas why this is occurring and why I keep getting tripped up by this?

**EDIT**: It seems that by not using jQuery's AJAX 'data' parameter, and just appending the values to the URL, it doesn't escape the JSON representations. Is there a clean way to do what jQuery does adding GET parameters without manually appending them?

Comment: Why have you got the `%22` parts (escaped quotes) in the URL? Have you tried removing them?

Comment: When the GET happens that's what it comes through as. The $.ajax with the "params" object escapes to that. I'm assuming that's why the dates are null too.

Comment: Well rather than assuming it, I would try it manually with a more expected URL - then if that works (which I'd hope it would) you can work on changing the AJAX to avoid the escaping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435090/how-do-i-prevent-jquery-ajax-to-encode-certain-chars-on-data-parameter

Comment: I think you won't face this problem using POST method instead of  GET

Answer (score 0):

try removing the use of ko.toJSON().
The date will be a property of your params object.

Jquery with dataType : 'json' will translate the date object properly.